# How can I add text into a certain area?

Tags: php

If I have a line like this,

```
<option value="someval">somval</option>
```

how can I position the cursor after the last quotation of value and put something like `abcdef`?

So the output would be

```
<option value="somval" abcdef>somval</option>
```

with [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)?

I want to do this dynamically and I can't figure out how to do it. I'm looking at `strpos()`, but I don't see how it can be done. I'll be posting a bunch of option tags into a textbox and code will be generated. so I'll have a lot of option fields.

@martin - Say I have a huge dropdown and each option lists a country that exists. Rather than having to manually type out something like this:

```
$query = $db->query("my query....");
while($row = $db->fetch($query)) {

<select name="thename">
    <option value="someval" <?php if($row['someval'] == 'someval') { print "selected"; } ?> >someval</option>
    <option value="someval" <?php if($row['someval'] == 'someval') { print "selected"; } ?> >someval</option>
    <option value="someval" <?php if($row['someval'] == 'someval') { print "selected"; } ?> >someval</option>
    ... Followed by 100 more, because there are a lot of locations to list.
</select>
```

How can I post all the options I have into a textbox and have the above code automatically generated to save a lot of time?

Comment: Can you post more code? Do you build this dynamically?

Comment: open your php editor place cursor next to quota and type " abcdef"... maybe you might want to rephrase the question, to get the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not very clear to me. You want load a set of option tags into your textbox? And after pressing submit or something, you want to create a dropdown list?

Comment: @martin check out my rephrase

Answer (score 2):

Using your example you would do:

```
while($row = $db->fetch($query)) {
    printf('<option value="someval"%s>someval</option>',
            ($row['someval'] == 'someval') ? ' selected="selected" ' : '');
}
```

This would go through the rows and output an option, replacing the `%s` with the attribute `selected="selected"` if `$row['someval']` is *equal* to `someval`. However, the above is rather pointless, because all option elements will have the same value and text, so try

```
while($row = $db->fetch($query)) {
    printf('<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
            $row['country-code'],
            ($row['country-code'] === $selection) ? ' selected="selected" ' : '',
            row['country-name']);
}
```

With `$selection` being anything you want to compare against. Replace the keys in $row with appropriate keys from in your database.

*Note: The usual disclaimers about securing your output apply*

Answer (score 0):

You could capture `(value=".+?")` and replace it with `$0 abcdef`.

```
<?php

  $string = '<option value="someval">someval</option>';
  print preg_replace("/(value=\".+?\")/i", "$0 abcdef", $string);

?>
```

Which outputs the following:

```
<option value="someval" abcdef>someval</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you can generate a whole string with any text you wish. Where do you have your original string? In a variable or a text file?